# Harmon.ie outlook side bar - some users not able to click into SP folder (updated with error log)

Tags: sharepoint-online, harmon.ie

We installed the Harmon.ie personal plan (harmon.ie add-in for outlook on W10 pro laptops of similar brand/model) for some of our users. After supplying their O365 credentials and SP URL, all users of one of our office groups are able to see the SP document library in the harmon side bar in outlook, including the folders / document sets within that library.

However, in the sidebar only some users can actually click into the folder / document set and see the contents (ie individual files). Others can click but the contents of the folder is not shown (in fact nothing happens on double click).

The users are all part of the same O365 group and the entire group has edit permission level for that document library. Users that can not properly use the sidebar have access to the folder and documents using SP online.

Any ideas on the possible cause and ways to resolve? Thanks for any help!

Update:
I looked into the error log (harmonie.log) and around the time the user clicked on a folder name in the add-in, the error logs lists numerous errors with similar headings (see below). The add-in 'hangs/stalls' for a couple of seconds, you can not highlight another folder and then it defreezes again. Lines from error log:

2018-05-17 15:01:21,046 WARN  [Worker-16] com.mainsoft.common.Job - Ignoring exception during job. System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.
[..] sublines of error removed
2018-05-17 15:01:21,060 ERROR [eclipse-CLR] com.mainsoft.common.JavaLogger - Rethrowing exception System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.
[..]
2018-05-17 15:01:27,842 WARN  [Worker-21] com.mainsoft.common.Job - Ignoring exception during job. System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.
[..]
2018-05-17 15:01:27,849 ERROR [eclipse-CLR] com.mainsoft.common.JavaLogger - Rethrowing exception System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.
[..]
2018-05-17 15:02:27,543 WARN  [Worker-21] com.mainsoft.common.Job - Ignoring exception during job. System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.
[..]
018-05-17 15:02:27,551 ERROR [eclipse-CLR] com.mainsoft.common.JavaLogger - Rethrowing exception System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.
[..]
018-05-17 15:02:27,558 ERROR [eclipse-CLR] com.mainsoft.sharepoint.sidebar.toolkit.DisplayMessagesHandler - The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden. System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.
[..]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to upgrade and install our latest 6.7 version from our web site.
Once you upgraded, make first sure the impacted users are able to open the document set from SharePoint web interface in IE (by using the same credentials)

Are the impacted user(s) able to see content when selecting No view from our view button? (orange button)
If not, gather the communication information between client (harmon.ie) and SharePoint server – we usually rely on Fiddler network tracing tool http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ Please download and install it. If your Sharepoint site uses HTTPS secure protocol – after installing Fiddler, please go under ‘Tools -> Fiddler Options’, select ‘HTTPS’ tab and enable the checkboxes (Capture HTTPS Traffic, Decrypt HTTPS Traffic, Ignore Server Certificate Errors).
If installed and configured successfully – restart Outlook, and reproduce the problem i.e. navigate inside the document set (let me know about its name, check also in no view). You should requests being registered in fiddler. Once the trace log is generated, save it via File -> Save All Sessions… and send me the generated .saz file

----- Jean